# Sync two instance of Redis server

Tags: session, redis, in-memory-database, redis-cluster

I have 2 instance of redis server, each instance is in different server. Every instance is connected to an web application. When I login to First application, it will store a session to redis in its server. I want to use this session in second application. How to copy exact session to another redis server every time one of them got new data? Is it handled by application or redis it self?

Note : **When Redis Server A got new data it will transfer it to Redis Server B, and when Redis Server B got new data it transfer it to Redis Server A.**

Comment: It seems that you need some sort of multi-master replication. Your Server A and Server B are connection to web applications and you need to have data on Server A and Server B replicated.

Comment: Why can't they both use the same master and failover to slave in case of error?